# Initializing templated, recursive, POD struct

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

I was experimenting with using template recursion to generate a nested POD structs, and I came across some behavior I wasn't expecting. Here's a simplified test case:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t size>
struct RecursiveStruct {
public:
    template <std::size_t start, std::size_t length>
    struct Builder {
        static const Builder value;
        static const size_t mid = start + length / 2;
        static const size_t end = start + length;
        Builder<start, mid - start> left;
        Builder<mid, end - mid> right;
    };

    template <std::size_t start>
    struct Builder<start, 1> {
        static const Builder value;
        int data;
    };

    static const Builder<0, size> result;
};

template<std::size_t size>
const typename RecursiveStruct<size>::template Builder<0, size>
        RecursiveStruct<size>::result = Builder<0, size>::value;

template<std::size_t size>
template<std::size_t start, std::size_t length>
const typename RecursiveStruct<size>::template Builder<start, length>
        RecursiveStruct<size>::Builder<start, length>::value
            = { Builder<start, mid - start>::value, Builder<mid, end - mid>::value };

template<std::size_t size>
template <std::size_t start>
const typename RecursiveStruct<size>::template Builder<start, 1>
        RecursiveStruct<size>::Builder<start, 1>::value = { 5 };

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::size_t;

int main() {
    cout << RecursiveStruct<1>::result.data << endl;
    cout << RecursiveStruct<2>::result.left.data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect this code to output

```
5
5
```

Indeed, that it what is generated when I compile with GCC 4.8.4 and 5.1.

However, compiling either with Clang (3.5 or 3.7) or Visual Studio 2010 instead results in

```
5
0
```

Is my code or my understanding of it wrong in some way, or do Clang and Visual Studio somehow both have bugs that result in the same erroneous output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both compilers are conforming as the order of initialization of static variables is unspecified. The clearest statement comes from a note in [basic.start.init]:

> *[ Note:* As a consequence, if the initialization of an object obj1 refers to an object obj2 of namespace scope
>   potentially requiring dynamic initialization and defined later in the same translation unit, it is unspecified
>   whether the value of obj2 used will be the value of the fully initialized obj2 (because obj2 was statically
>   initialized) or will be the value of obj2 merely zero-initialized. For example,
>
> ```
> inline double fd() { return 1.0; }
> extern double d1;
> double d2 = d1; // unspecified:
> // may be statically initialized to 0.0 or
> // dynamically initialized to 0.0 if d1 is
> // dynamically initialized, or 1.0 otherwise
> double d1 = fd(); // may be initialized statically or dynamically to 1.0
> ```
>
> *—end note ]*

In our case, `Builder<start, 1>::value` was statically initialized, but everything else is dynamically uninitialized - so it's unspecified as to the fully initialized `Builder<start, 1>::value` is used or not.

A workaround is to use the construct on first use idiom and do something like (I took the liberty of pulling out `Builder` from `RecursiveStruct` for simplicity - it exhibits the same behavior either way):

```
template <std::size_t start, std::size_t length>
struct Builder
{
    static const size_t mid = start + length / 2;
    static const size_t end = start + length;    

    static const Builder value() {
        static const Builder value_{ 
            Builder<start, mid - start>::value(), 
            Builder<mid, end - mid>::value() 
        };
        return value_;
    }

    Builder<start, mid - start> left;
    Builder<mid, end - mid> right;
};

template <std::size_t start>
struct Builder<start, 1> {
    static const Builder value() {
        static const Builder value_{5};
        return value_;
    }

    int data;
};

template<std::size_t size>
struct RecursiveStruct {
public:
    static const Builder<0, size> result;
};

template <std::size_t size>
const Builder<0, size> RecursiveStruct<size>::result = Builder<0, size>::value();
```

This prints `5` on both compilers.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, I don't think that note would apply here. My understanding is that undefined initialization applies to dynamic initialization. That is, initialization that happens at program startup. As I understand it, the reason the example given is undefined is because `fd()` may or may not be inlined by the compiler, thus `d1` may be either dynamically or statically initialized, which is why `d2` is unspecified. In my case, everything is const POD, so it should all be statically initialized.

Comment: It may still be unspecified behavior, but if so, I do not believe it is the reference note which makes it so.

Comment: @rkjnsn Static initialization requires that it be initialized with a constant expression - so some of your objects are dynamically initialized.

Comment: Hmm... okay. That makes sense, but is quite unfortunate. I do need it to be a statically initialized constant for my use case. I know C++11 has constexpr, which could probably do it, but is there any way in C++03? (Maybe that should be a new question.)

Comment: @rkjnsn Don't think so in C++03, but couldn't hurt to ask!